# Correlation analysis between stock prices

Tags: excel, statistics, covariance, correlation

Let us consider following stock prices taken from yahoo.finance.com:

```
Date        Open    High    Low     Close   Volume      Adj Close
3/4/2013    23.15   23.84   23.03   23.67   30908300    23.3
2/25/2013   23.5    23.53   22.81   23.19   40710800    22.83
2/19/2013   23.42   23.75   23.12   23.39   38743400    23.03
2/11/2013   22.49   23.55   22.35   23.29   46448500    22.74
2/4/2013    22.41   22.62   22.27   22.5    34498100    21.97
1/28/2013   22.44   22.64   22.18   22.62   39634900    22.09
1/22/2013   22.18   22.31   21.75   22.29   47826300    21.77
1/14/2013   21.18   22.19   21.01   22.04   54826000    21.52
1/7/2013    21.16   21.24   20.68   21.13   35304100    20.63
12/31/2012  20.29   21.54   20.26   21.2    45796500    20.7
12/24/2012  20.79   20.96   20.42   20.44   28597100    19.96
12/17/2012  21.69   21.95   20.56   20.88   70719700    20.39
12/10/2012  21.43   21.95   21.36   21.62   39455500    20.92
12/3/2012   21.18   21.48   20.71   21.46   35913000    20.77
11/26/2012  20.88   21.36   20.5    21.13   36203100    20.45
11/19/2012  20.41   21.04   20.37   21.04   35401500    20.36
11/12/2012  21.04   21.14   19.87   20.15   45095400    19.5
11/5/2012   21.2    21.78   20.7    21      37812800    20.32
11/2/2012   21.53   21.68   21.26   21.31   47475200    20.62
```

And i want to do correlation matrix between for example Volume and Low Close variable. I used correlation function from data analysis toolbox from excel, but I got only one side matrix, like this:

```
            Close           Volume
Close       1   
Volume      -0.117267345    1
```

It does not show me correlation coefficients up side of main diagonal, why? Maybe it is symmetric and because of this?

Comment: Any chance for better interpunction? Do you want coefficients between Volume, Low and Close?

Comment: yes s exactly,in this case between volume and close

Comment: each one is a separately column,with its own name,just because of formatting i can't separate it

Comment: would **=CORREL(** work?

Answer (score 1):

The correlation matrix is necessarily symmetric, so the above the diagonal element in your case is -0.117257345.   If you check [the documentation on the correl function](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/correl-HP005209023.aspx), and look at the defining equation, you can see that it is symmetric with respect to exchanging `X<->Y`